# Why the domain of the cube root function are all the real numbers?

Tags: roots

since it can also be written as x^(1/3) and therefore 1/(x^3) and this would not make sense for x=0 because of the division with 0. So why is 0 in the domain?

Comment: because in most of all cases $x^{1/3}\ne \frac1{x^3}$. And because obviously $0^3=0$ (similary, $0$ is also in the domain of the square root function)

Comment: Note:  $1/x^3=x^{-3}$

Comment: @kay ?? What division by 0? It is not true that $x^{\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{x^3}$. Maybe you are thinking of $x^{-3}$ which not the cube root.

Comment: Why are you concerned about zero? We know that $0 \cdot 0 \cdot 0=0$, hence, by definition, $\sqrt[3] 0=0$

Comment: Absolutely right, I am sorry it was a moment of unclarity for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y=x^\frac13\implies x=y^3$, on the contrary, $y=\frac{1}{x^3}\implies x=(\frac 1y)^\frac13$

They aren't the same (except when $x=1$), because $\frac{1}{a^n}$ is written as $a^{-n}$, not $a^{\frac1n}$

Notice that $\frac{a^m}{a^n}=a^ma^{-n}=a^{m-n}$ holds with this notation